# Borrowing the mutable member used inside the loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The problem I want to solve is:

> Given the recursively nested data structure, eg. a JSON tree, and a path pointing to (possibly non-existent) element inside it, return the mutable reference of the element, that's the closest to given path.

Example: if we have JSON document in form `{ a: { b: { c: "foo" } } }` and a path `a.b.d`, we want to have a mutable pointer to value stored under key "b".

This is a code snippet, what I've got so far:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum Json {
    Number(i64),
    Bool(bool),
    String(String),
    Array(Vec<Json>),
    Object(HashMap<String, Json>)
}

struct Pointer<'a, 'b> {
    value: &'a mut Json,
    path: Vec<&'b str>,
    position: usize
}

/// Return a mutable pointer to JSON element having shared 
/// the nearest common path with provided JSON. 
fn nearest_mut<'a,'b>(obj: &'a mut Json, path: Vec<&'b str>) -> Pointer<'a,'b> {
    let mut i = 0;
    let mut current = obj;
    for &key in path.iter() {
        match current {
            Json::Array(array) => {
                match key.parse::<usize>() {
                    Ok(index) => {
                        match array.get_mut(index) {
                            Some(inner) => current = inner,
                            None => break,
                        }
                    },
                    _ => break,
                }
            } ,
            Json::Object(map) => {
                match map.get_mut(key) {
                    Some(inner) => current = inner,
                    None => break
                }
            },
            _ => break,
        };
        i += 1;
    }
    Pointer { path, position: i, value: current }
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't pass through Rust's borrow checker, as `current` is borrowed as mutable reference twice, once inside match statement and once at the end of the function, when constructing the pointer method.

I've tried a different approaches, but not figured out how to achieve the goal (maybe going the unsafe path).

Comment: How about using an [Rc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html)

Comment: Take an additional closure parameter, and return a `Result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely misread your question and I owe you an apology.

You cannot do it in one pass - you're going to need to do a read-only pass to find the nearest path (or exact path), and then a read-write pass to actually extract the reference, or pass a mutator function in the form of a closure.

I've [implemented](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f3059f46c0f83bcae1714c7cfab29b4) the two-pass method for you. Do note that it is still pretty performant:

```
fn nearest_mut<'a, 'b>(obj: &'a mut Json, path: Vec<&'b str>) -> Pointer<'a, 'b> {
    let valid_path = nearest_path(obj, path);
    exact_mut(obj, valid_path).unwrap()
}
fn exact_mut<'a, 'b>(obj: &'a mut Json, path: Vec<&'b str>) -> Option<Pointer<'a, 'b>> {
    let mut i = 0;
    let mut target = obj;
    for token in path.iter() {
        i += 1;
        // borrow checker gets confused about `target` being mutably borrowed too many times because of the loop
        // this once-per-loop binding makes the scope clearer and circumvents the error
        let target_once = target;
        let target_opt = match *target_once {
            Json::Object(ref mut map) => map.get_mut(*token),
            Json::Array(ref mut list) => match token.parse::<usize>() {
                Ok(t) => list.get_mut(t),
                Err(_) => None,
            },
            _ => None,
        };
        if let Some(t) = target_opt {
            target = t;
        } else {
            return None;
        }
    }
    Some(Pointer {
        path,
        position: i,
        value: target,
    })
}
/// Return a mutable pointer to JSON element having shared
/// the nearest common path with provided JSON.
fn nearest_path<'a, 'b>(obj: &'a Json, path: Vec<&'b str>) -> Vec<&'b str> {
    let mut i = 0;
    let mut target = obj;
    let mut valid_paths = vec![];
    for token in path.iter() {
        // borrow checker gets confused about `target` being mutably borrowed too many times because of the loop
        // this once-per-loop binding makes the scope clearer and circumvents the error
        let target_opt = match *target {
            Json::Object(ref map) => map.get(*token),
            Json::Array(ref list) => match token.parse::<usize>() {
                Ok(t) => list.get(t),
                Err(_) => None,
            },
            _ => None,
        };
        if let Some(t) = target_opt {
            target = t;
            valid_paths.push(*token)
        } else {
            return valid_paths;
        }
    }
    return valid_paths
}
```

The principle is simple - I reused the method I wrote in my initial question in order to get the nearest valid path (or exact path).

From there, I feed that straight into the function that I had in my original answer, and since I am certain the path is valid (from the prior function call) I can safely `unwrap()` :-)

Comment: While this is interesting answer, it's not complete - as the `nearest` name suggests, the goal is not to return an element, that matches the path, but when none matches, return the closest one - please read the example I've attached at the beginning.

Comment: @BartoszSypytkowski Edited with an apology and some new code. Thank you for pointing it out, I completely missed it